# Python: Open file and scraping and splitting text and assigning variables

Tags: python, file, variables, split

Hi I am having trouble figuring out how to access a file and scrape the data and assign variables to the specific numbers within the text.

The text file is as follows:

color red

rect -100 75 200 50

COLOR green

RECT -100 25 200 50

color blue

rect -100 -25 200 50

I need to assign individual variables to red, rect and each individual number. I am using Turtle to draw pictures and have drawn four different pictures. I just need to figure out how to assign the variables and drop into the functions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning variables to each shape, color, and value you can create a list for each shape like so

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    obj = []
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n': 
            continue

        l = line.split()
        if l[0].lower() == 'color':
            color = l[1].lower()
        else:
            obj.append([l[0].lower()] + [color] + l[1:])
    print obj

[['rect', 'red', '-100', '75', '200', '50'], 
 ['rect', 'green', '-100', '25', '200', '50'], 
 ['rect', 'blue', '-100', '-25', '200', '50']]
```

Then you can just reference your list for all the shapes, colors, and values

Comment: you should use for loop gards when possible. it will improve readability. `if line == "\n": continue` http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/77591/

Comment: @Lynch Oh thanks for catching that, I usually do that but wasn't thinking